# How to create binary file of specific size?

Tags: java, file

How can I create one binary file of size 250KB and another one of 1MB using Java?
Is it possible?

Comment: You open a stream to write to a file and write that specific amount of data.... Yes it is possible.

Comment: Write 256,000 bytes to one file and 1,048,576 bytes to another.

Comment: So a 250KB file is actually 256,000 bytes? thanks for the help

Comment: For memory 1 MB is typically 1024 * 1024 bytes, but for disk space 1,000,000 byte is often used. When you have GB this can make an 8% difference.

Answer (score 6):

```
 new RandomAccessFile("file.file", "rw").setLength(1048576);
```

Comment: You don't have to close that file?

Comment: To be correct, yes. But the above seems to be sufficient to create file, in my system at least. To guarantee this, use "rws" as mode argument: *Open for reading and writing, as with "rw", and also require that every update to the file's content or metadata be written synchronously to the underlying storage device.*

Answer (score 1):

```
FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream("a.bin");
byte[] buf = new byte[250*1024];
s.write(buf);
s.flush();
s.close();
```

Comment: I don't think allocating an entire array that size is a very memory-efficient way to tackle that problem. (But then again, I don't know Java.)

Comment: Typical default heap size is 64-256MB. Do not hesitate for 1MB that goes out of scope quickly. But if you like, use smaller chunks or write byte by byte.

Comment: In Java 6 server JVM, the default heap size is 1/4 of main memory. If you set the maximum heap size to 1 MB, the JVM won't start.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public voidwriteFile(String path, int bytes) throws Exception {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    File f=null;
    try {
        f = new File(path + "/tmp.txt");
        f.createNewFile();
        byte[] buf = new byte[bytes];
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        outputStream.write(buf);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(f!=null){
                f.delete();
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```